# Creating a java project in eclipse 3.1.2 - Is the JRE version correct?

Tags: eclipse, java

I have downloaded eclipse 3.1.2 to be able to make use of a particular library (Indus - http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/). Under the `'Create a java project'` dialog, the JDK section is automatically set to 1.4, which is fine. However, I don't have jdk 1.4 installed on my machine. Is it included with Eclipse 3.1.2? Also when I right click on the project and go to `'Properties'` and select `'Java build Path'`, the jre is set to jre 6. Should this not be a jre suitable for java 1.4? Could someone also explain to me exactly what the jre is and how it ties in with the jdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Related question](http://www.coderanch.com/t/540908/java/java/Java-Platform)

You should be able to find older jdk's or jre's (like [here](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/1.4.2_19/index.html)). If you compile the Eclipse project for a certain version, newer jre's should be able to run them too.